# Formatting links so that they are displayed side by side and to the top left of a website in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have made a list of links in html for a prototype of a website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stuffy_stylesheets.css">
        <title> INF </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id= "content">
            <p>More Stuff</p>
            <p>Even More Stuff</p>
        </div>

        <div id= "list">
            <ul id = "menu">

            <li><a href= "pg2.html"> wad</a></li>
            <li><a href= "pg3.html"> wad</a></li>
            <li><a href= "pg4.html"> wad</a></li>
            <li><a href= "pg5.html"> wad</a></li>
            </ul>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

These pages so far mean absolutely nothing, however,I wanted to style and format the links so that they are towards the top left of the web page and inline with each other, to do this, I have experimented with `display: inline-block`, however, for some odd reason that doesn't seem to work. So I was wondering what code I would need to add to format it this way. My CSS is below:

```
body{
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #434447;

}
#content
{
   color: #eaeaea;
   text-align: center;

}
#list{
  display:flex;
}
#menu
{
  padding: 10px;
  float:left;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 15%;
}
#menu li
{
  list-style: none;
  width:10em;
  display: block;
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:outset;
  border colour: black;
  padding: 3px 2px 3px 2px;
  color: #545456;
  background: #babbc1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;

}
#menu a
{
  color:#545456;
  background: #babbc1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#menu li:hover
{
   border-style:inset;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you seem to be doing wrong here is the `width: 15%` that you've applied on the `#menu`.

Skipping that property and adding `display: inline-block` on your `li` elements should solve this.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maitreyjukar/sq03zhmf/) for the same.

P.S. - While you're at it, change `border colour` to `border-color`.

Comment: Also, why does the width at 15% matter?

Comment: Sorry about that, weird little OCD of mine.

Comment: Well, the `width: 15%` is restricting the `li` tags from spreading out. The `li` tags are longer than what the 15% width computes out to be and so fall one below the other. Applying `width: 100%` or not applying width at all should solve it given that the width isn't of much importance here.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have another question, when I use the inline-block display the border-style isn't applied to the links anymore for some weird reason

Comment: I can't seem to replicate what you're saying. The border seems to be visible around the links wrapped in the `li` tags. At least I can see them in the fiddle that I've shared. Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: Before I used inline-block the borders would change from inset to outset when hovered to give a 3d effect, but now f or some reason this doesn't happen

Comment: I have realised my error, I just couldn't see the 3d effect because I had changed the background colour, and by changing the border colour it starts to work again, thanks

Comment: Good to see that everything's falling *in line* now.

Comment: I was trying to think of a good pun as a return, but I got nothing, but good pun

Answer (score 0):

Change your css code to something like this.

```
body {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #434447;
}

#content {
  color: #eaeaea;
  text-align: center;
}

#list {
  display: flex;
}

#menu {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#menu li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 10em;
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: outset;
  border colour: black;
  padding: 3px 2px 3px 2px;
  color: #545456;
  background: #babbc1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#menu a {
  color: #545456;
  background: #babbc1;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu li:hover {
  border-style: inset;
}
```